# ValueError at /profile/ in Django: didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django

I have this line of code in models.py

```
 @login_required
 def user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
        else:
            user = request.user
            profile = user.profile
            form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
            args = {}
            args.update(csrf(request))
            args['form'] = form
            return render(request, 'profile.tml', args)
```

and in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from models import UserProfile


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('address', 'contactnos')
```

in my loggedin.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2> Hi {{ full_name }} you are logged in!</h2>
<p>click <a href="/accounts/logout/">here</a> to logout. </p>

<p>Click <a href="/profile/">here</a> to edit your profile info </p>

{% endblock %}
```

The error is says:

ValueError at /profile/
The view userprofile.views.user_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't accounted for a `GET` scenario; what happens when the view is not accessed via `POST`? You return nothing, therefore you get this error.

Return an `http.HttpResponse` when `request.method != 'POST'`

Perhaps you meant to un-indent the bottom half `else` statement.

You haven't accounted for a `GET` scenario; what happens when the view is not accessed via `POST`? You return nothing, therefore you get this error.

Return an `http.HttpResponse` when `request.method != 'POST'`

Perhaps you meant to un-indent the bottom half `else` statement.

```
@login_required
 def user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
    else:
        user = request.user
        profile = user.profile
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'profile.tml', args)
```

Comment: the profile page shows when `request.method != 'POST'` is used..however it doesn't save a value and the same error occurred again.

Comment: Sachi your current code would not exhibit that behavior. Please try posting your code again. Your `user_profile` view currently returns `None` on `GET`, and always a response on `POST`.

Comment: It should save value using `POST` method and if the form is valid and redirects to `loggedin.html`. When the user edit the profile again the old value should populate the form. Sorry, but I just learn Django a week ago.